# Firebase hosting / auth / cloudstore hosted on a server in Australia

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a requirement to host a web app that uses Firebase services on a server physically located in Australia. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so is there any documentation available around this? I would be using Firebase Hosting / Auth / Firestore - all would need to be hosted in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

- Firebase Hosting is hosted on a global CDN network. You can't restrict where it is server or accessed from.
- Firebase Authentication data is also stored globally, outside of your control.
- I'm not sure what Cloudstore is, but given the above two answers you might already want to look at alternative products.

Comment: Just to confirm - setting the "Default GCP resource location" to say "australia-southeast1". Does this mean the data will only be stored on servers in Australia? Or will it still be on other servers outside of Australia?

Comment: The behavior depends on the GCP product. There are > 100 of them, so it's impossible to answer in general - that why I trued to answer for the specific products I recognized in your question.